# Where does Windows 7 store "warning" information about a .LNK? (And how to remove the warning)

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, security-warning

I have a program installed. Doesn't really matter which.

If I double click on the executable file, it launches with no problems.

If I create a link in a taskbar or in the menu bar, clicking the link opens a warning dialog: "Open File - Security Warning" detailing that "While files from the Internet can be useful, this file type can potentially harm your computer".

I know that I can [get rid of the warning](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/182353-open-file-security-warning-enable-disable.html), but I **don't** want to remove security from *all* links. Only from *this* one, and I want to grant UAC access when I do so. *After that* the link should be vetted and open with no further ado *ever*.

If I create the link on the Desktop, **and then copy it in the Menu bar**, and then I **move** the link in the same menu bar, I end up with *two* links on the same menu bar.

The first one opens the dialog. The second does not: it directly opens the application.

At that point I got curious: what is the difference between the two files?

- file name: no.
- file contents: neither. They have the same MD5 hash.
- attributes: no joy, they have identical attributes.
- perhaps an Alternate Data Stream? Could have been -- but isn't. Neither .LNK file has ADS attached.
- in the registy? Makes little sense, but again seems to there be nothing in the registry to that effect.
- MFT metadata? I tried using [this tool](http://www.williballenthin.com/forensics/mft/get_file_info/) and possibly made some mistake, but I didn't find anything obvious (I'm not too sure there wasn't, mind you).

I have tried peeking at the $MFT metadata and found a difference, of which I do not know the significance, between the "General information" fields of the two files. NTFS Explorer reports the sections as identical; actually they are not. After the date fields and the DOS attributes, there are two hex sequences which are different:

```
File1
00 00 00 00 88 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
10 45 41 22 00 00 00 00

File2
00 00 00 00 A6 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
18 44 41 22 00 00 00 00
```

If the differenc had been one bit only I would be sure, but that's not the case. I'm not too sanguine about modifying the $MFT at random to see what happens - I'm somewhat scared of what *might* happen. And moreover, it seems silly to me that a not unreasonable operation ("*remove the warning from this link here*"), for which there even exists an easiy found workaround ("*create the link on the desktop and move from there to wherever it really needed to go*") should be so complicated and even need a third-party tool.

I expect there should be some bundled tool or procedure to the same effect, to allow editing this mysterious and elusive "Internet Warning" flag.

So *where* is it stored? And is there a simple way of removing it (for the next time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information was actually in the DACL zone and can be edited from the command line using [the appropriate tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx).

This removes the warning from "filename.lnk" (has to be run from command shell, I use CMD for old times' sake):

```
ICACLS filename.lnk /SetIntegrityLevel M /L
```

A whole directory tree of links can be treated with

```
ICACLS *.lnk /T /L /SetIntegrityLevel M
```

ran from the root folder.

I think it would be possible to create a shell operation ("Unblock") that could run the ICACLS command on right-clicking a .LNK file. A beginning tutorial could be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/) (Vista, but Seven shouldn't be too different).

## Create "Unblock" menu command

1. Open `REGEDIT` utility. *Usual cautions apply.* **REGEDIT can wreck your system!**
2. Open the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` hive.
3. Locate the `lnkfile` entry.
4. Right-click on lnkfile and choose "New > Key".
5. Create a new key called "shell".
6. Repeat above steps to create a key called "Unblock" inside "shell".
7. Repeat above to create "command" inside "Unblock"
8. Edit the Default value of the Unblock key so it reads

   ```
   CMD.EXE /S /C "ICACLS %1 /L /SetIntegrityLevel med"
   ```

Close `REGEDIT`.

Now locate the LNK that was giving you trouble. Right-click on it; you should be able to see a "Unblock" entry in the menu. Select it.

An UAC prompt appears that needs to be agreed to, and a warning may also appears checking whether you're really sure to do this.

Now if you double click again on the link, the application is launched without any further troubles. **If you had an UAC warning and not a file open warning**, then the above procedure is not enough. You also need to right-click on the link, and from its properties choose "Run as Administrator" (you may have to do the same to the application itself).

Tested and working on Windows 7 Pro and Ultimate.

Comment: Works on Windows 10 too.